# Открытие SerialPort с использованием библиотеки JSSC

Tags: java, usb, jssc, serialport

Всем привет. Пытаюсь использовать библиотеку jssc для работы с usb. Но при вызове метода открытия пора, вылетает ошибка(прикреплю ниже). Использую JDK8, Win10-64.

```
 // writing to port
 SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort(portName);
 try {
     // opening port
     serialPort.openPort(); // тут вылетает с ошибкой
```

Ошибка:

```
 A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000007110b5db, pid=12148, tid=0x00000000000010e8

 JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_261-b12) (build 1.8.0_261-b12)
 Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.261-b12 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
 Problematic frame:
 C  [jSSC-2.8_x86_64.dll+0xb5db]

 Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows

 If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
 The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
 See problematic frame for where to report the bug.


---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x000002480cda8000):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=4328, stack(0x0000008544100000,0x0000008544200000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x000000000d061ae8

---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 10.0 , 64 bit Build 14393 (10.0.14393.3630)

CPU:total 4 (initial active 4) (2 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 142 stepping 9, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, avx, avx2, aes, clmul, erms, 3dnowpref, lzcnt, ht, tsc, tscinvbit, bmi1, bmi2, adx

Memory: 4k page, physical 8262884k(1844036k free), swap 12550176k(1770012k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.261-b12) for windows-amd64 JRE (1.8.0_261-b12), built on Jun 18 2020 06:56:32 by "" with unknown MS VC++:1916

time: Tue Oct  6 10:26:11 2020
timezone: RTZ 2 (ceia)
elapsed time: 54 seconds (0d 0h 0m 54s)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56482406/fatal-error-attempting-to-write-to-com-port-using-jssc-exception-access-violati/56547566#56547566

Comment: можно вообще поискать что-нибудь другое, например рабочий порт RXTX под яву https://github.com/github-byl/Java-RxTx-in-Windows-10-USB-COM-ports вроде код в примере очень простой и понятный.